# parsing a string in using strpos to find text in reverse

Tags: php

using:

```
$result = "<TD><TD><TD><TD><TD><TD>Desired Text</TD></TR></TABLE>"


$find = '</TABLE>';
$pos = strpos($result, $find);
```

I get the location of where $find begins.

What I want to extract is 'Desired Text'

As you can see there is not a unique identifier to look for to set-off or easily locate 'Desired Text'. But there is '<TD>'.

What I want to do is find '</TABLE>' then work back from there and get the first instance of '<TD>'.

For example the position of '</TABLE>' is at 47, and the first instance of '<TD>' going back from '</TABLE>' is 22 characters away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work:

```
<?php
$result = "<TD><TD><TD><TD><TD><TD>Desired Text</TD></TR></TABLE>";

$pos = strrpos(substr($result,0,strrpos($result,'</TABLE>')),'<TD>');

echo substr($result,$pos+strlen('<TD>'));
```

Of course you could use in this case also:

```
echo strip_tags($result);
```